# Why starting a second Activity crashes while passing data via Intent in onClick method

Tags: android, android-intent, start-activity

Here, in my Custom Adapter class, while i am tracing the error which i have found after pressing on the image, it goes through the onClick method successfully, attain the intent, but it crashes when it attempts to start the second Activity.

```
package com.example.prof_mohamed.movieapp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Prof-Mohamed on 8/3/2016.
 */

public class ImagesAdapter extends         RecyclerView.Adapter<ImagesAdapter.ViewHOlder> {
    private List<MovieEntity> feedItemList;

    private Context mContext;


    public ImagesAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<MovieEntity>     feedItemList) {
        this.feedItemList=feedItemList;
        this.mContext= context;
    }

    @Override
    public ImagesAdapter.ViewHOlder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,     int i) {
        View view =     LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_layout, null);

        RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder=new ViewHOlder(view);
        return (ViewHOlder) viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHOlder customViewholder, final int     i) {

        final MovieEntity feedItem=feedItemList.get(i);
            Picasso.with(mContext).load(feedItem.getPOSTER_PATH_STRING()).into(customView    holder.one_img);

        customViewholder.one_text.setText(feedItem.getTITLE_STRING());
        customViewholder.one_img.setOnClickListener(new     View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext,DetailActivity.class)
                        .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,feedItem);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return (null!=feedItemList?feedItemList.size():0);
    }

    public class ViewHOlder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        protected ImageView one_img;
        protected TextView one_text;

        public ViewHOlder(View converview) {
            super(converview);

            this.one_img = (ImageView)     converview.findViewById(R.id.img_view);
            this.one_text = (TextView)     converview.findViewById(R.id.txt_poster_title);
        }
    }
}
```

Here are my second Activity, which i have to send my data from the first Activity to it :

```
package com.example.prof_mohamed.movieapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static String mMovieStr;

        TextView txtTitle=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_title);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);

        Intent intent = getIntent();

        if(intent != null&&intent.hasExtra(intent.EXTRA_TEXT)){
        mMovieStr=intent.getStringExtra(intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
        txtTitle.setText(mMovieStr);
    }
}
}
```

This is my error result :

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
                      at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:1278)
                      at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:1265)
                      at com.example.prof_mohamed.movieapp.ImagesAdapter$1.onClick(ImagesAdapter.java:52)
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4432)
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18339)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5283)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

and after editing these lines inside the onClick method

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
Intent intent = new Intent(mContext,DetailActivity.class)
                    .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,feedItem);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
```

it gave me a Null pointer Exception of the txtTitle (TextView) in the DetailActivity.java class.

Can anybody help me to solve this problem. your response will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you check the error logs and see if doing something on txtTitle is giving null pointer exception ?

Comment: @AmanSinghal I have edited my post to include the error logs results, please review it in the above post

Comment: you pass a data object into intent, then getString on the other side? won't that cause problems? shouldn't you be passing `feedItem.getTITLE_STRING()`?

Comment: i think passing this data object her efeedItem.getTITLE_STRING() is true, but it didn't stop here it stops in this line: mContext.startActivity(intent); why !

Comment: you can start you activity before add flag like  intend.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)

Comment: after using this line, it gave me for a first time java.lang.NullPointerException .... what is the null value here !?

Comment: @AmanSinghal Dear, it found the txtTitle  as a null value as u expected, what should i do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the following code after creating the intent

```
myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

Comment: after using this line, it's the first time to give me a java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Great, you want me to help you with why it is giving that exception, or you have figured it out ?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(mContext,DetailActivity.class)
                       .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,feedItem);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
mContext.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: It worked with me by using    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In your adapter class you are passing object,but in second activity you are trying to getStringExtra()

Read this it will be helpful

[How to send an object from one Android Activity to another using Intents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139134/how-to-send-an-object-from-one-android-activity-to-another-using-intents)

Comment: @ Ramit, if it works then please accept the answer, so that othe people can also get help

Comment: Prof-Mohamed Atef can accept this, but plus one from my side :)

Comment: i haven't resolved it yet, as soon as i find the appropriate one, i will accept it

Comment: Can you please post your updated code with logcat error.

Answer (score -1):

Please check you defined DetailActivity in manifest file.

Comment: these are my activities in the Manifest file :

<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".DetailActivity"></activity>
Is this a true or should it contains a <intent-filter> tags also like .MainActivity ?

Comment: In ImagesAdapter constructor you are passing activity context or not ?

Comment: I think shahid17june has shared correct answer. Please try.

Answer (score -1):

feedItem is an object. You are passing this with intent and trying to get it from second activity as String, and that is the problem.